# Unable to Iterate through a hashtable using enumeration in java

Tags: java, collections, enumeration

This is the code where I am trying to print the key but it never gets executed rather it just goes to the the last line and throws null pointer exception.

```
Enumeration<String> keys = states.keys();
        int max=0;
        String maxClass="";
        while(keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            System.out.println(key);
                if(states.get(key)>=max)
                {
                    max=states.get(key);
                    maxClass=key;
                }
                System.out.println(maxClass);
        }
        System.out.println(maxClass);
        Category c = classes.get(maxClass);
        c.add(p);
```

this is the complete code of the classify function.

```
static void classify(ArrayList<Point> cities,Hashtable<String,Category> classes)
{
    for(Point p: cities)
     {
        ArrayList<Point> nbours = new ArrayList<Point>();
        nbours.addAll(getNbours( p,cities));
        // System.out.println(p.city);
        Hashtable<String,Integer> states = new  Hashtable<String,Integer>();
        for(Point pt : nbours)
        {
                //System.out.println(pt.city);

                if(states.containsKey(pt.state))
                {
                    int cnt = states.get(pt.state) + 1;
                    states.remove(pt.state);
                    states.put(pt.state,cnt);
                    //states.add(state,);
                }
                else
                {
                    states.put(pt.state,1);
                }
                //System.out.println(states.get(pt.state));
        }

        Enumeration<String> keys = states.keys();
        int max=0;
        String maxClass="";
        System.out.println(keys);
        while(keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            System.out.println(key);
                if(states.get(key)>=max)
                {
                    max=states.get(key);
                    maxClass=key;
                }
                System.out.println(maxClass);
        }
        System.out.println(maxClass);
        Category c = classes.get(maxClass);
        c.add(p);
        System.out.println(p.city+ "Classified");
        nbours.clear();

    }
```

Comment: Well it sounds like your hashtable is empty... if you don't believe that to be the case, please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: where does it throws NPE .. show us stacktrace

Comment: @sansix: The OP said it's the last line... which would be correct if the table is empty, because `classes.get("")` presumably returns null...

Comment: @JonSkeet ohh now I see

Comment: @JonSkeet well the hashtable doesnt seem to be empty as i tried printing the values of it in the loop above and it was displaying all the values.

Comment: Well if you gave us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we wouldn't have to guess, would we? It's not clear why you're using Hashtable instead of HashMap, or Enumeration instead of Iterator, mind you...

Comment: Before getting and using the `Category` from `classes,` check for it with `classes.containsKey(maxClass)`

Comment: Why a hashtable instead of a hashmap?

Comment: I had to go through my code again and found the bug. @JonSkeet thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the execution reaches the last line and exists with NullPointerException, then "c" is null.
That means that the call `Category c = classes.get(maxClass);` returns null. Check if the key in **maxClass** is available in classes object.